# How to pass textbox value to controller

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a textbox like below

```
   @using (Html.BeginForm("checkUserType", "Place", new {type =  }))
    {
        <div id="login">
            <div class="userNameLabel">UserName</div>
            <div class="userNameField"><input type="text" id="txtUserName"/><span><input type="button" value="ok" id="ok" /></span></div>
        </div>
    }
```

I want to pass the textbox value to my controller. For that I used the below code, but it's not working...
Pls help...

Action method

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult checkUserType(string type)
        {
            var elements = from element in db.USERS
                           where element.UserType == type
                           select element;
            if (elements == null)
            {
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            else
            {
                return RedirectToAction("Place/Index");
            }
        }
```

Comment: Please show your action method, also if you are going for GET request than your code needs to be changed at least like this `window.location.href = '@Url.Action( "checkUserType", "Place" )' + '?type=' + type;` or like this if the `type` parameter is being taken from the route `window.location.href = '@Url.Action( "checkUserType", "Place" )' + '/' + type;`

Comment: @tpeczek- I edited my code.Hope you can see it.

Comment: Then you should go for the `Form` in order to have POST request (you should look at @NeerajDubey answer).

Comment: @tpeczek-By doing like Neeraj said. I got a problem

Comment: What kind of problem?

Comment: How to take the value of textbox is passed through form.. I edited my code

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this once

```
window.location.href = '@Url.Action( "checkUserType", "Place" )?type='+type
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
<h2>Index</h2>
<% Html.BeginForm("Search", "Employee");%>
<table>
   <tr>
    <td>
        Name:
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type="text" id="SearchText" name="SearchText" style="width: 325px" />
    </td>
    <td> 
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type="submit" id="Search" value="Search" />
    </td>
</tr>
</table>
<% Html.EndForm();%>
```

your action goes like this...

```
public ActionResult Search(string searchText)
{ 
 }
```

Hope it helps you

Answer (score 0):

MVC will map your names of inputs to parameters of your method.

However, your current input doesn't specify a name:

```
<input type="text" id="txtUserName"/>
```

So add that:

```
<input type="text" name="type" id="txtUserName"/>
```

And it will map to the parameter. And take away the anonymous object from the `BeginForm` since that value will be provided by the input field, so doen't need to be in the `form`'s action.

Answer (score 0):

I just update your code try this

```
 @using (Html.BeginForm("checkUserType", "Place"))
    {
        <div id="login">
            <div class="userNameLabel">
                UserName</div>
            <div class="userNameField">
                <input type="text" id="txtUserName" name="UserName" /><span><input type="submit" value="ok" id="ok" /></span></div>
        </div>
    }
```

and controller

```
 public ActionResult checkUserType(string UserName)
        {
 string _data = UserName;


        }
```